# rc.local Teamspeak autostart

Tags: unix, freebsd, teamspeak

I would like to auto start Teamspeak server in case of a machine restart, to do that I made this entry into the `/etc/rc.local`:

`/bin/sh /home/derv__2014532/voice/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh restart`

Basically it works and the command is being run, however Teamspeak server is closing immadiately telling `telnet connection closed`. If I manually start using the same command, it works just fine.

Entire `rc.local` file content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Teamspeak boot
/bin/sh /home/derv__2014532/voice/teamspeak/ts3server_startscript.sh restart

exit 0
```

Is there any reason that `rc.local` might not work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can install teamspeak 3.0.13.5 from the ports system. You will find it in `/usr/ports/audio/teamspeak3-server/`.

Note that teamspeak 3 does not run on FreeBSD 9 nor FreeBSD 11 at this time, according to the port makefile.

This port comes with a startup script that will be installed in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/`. (you will find it's template in `/usr/ports/audio/teamspeak3-server/files/teamspeak.in`.) Just put `teamspeak_enable="YES"` in `/etc/rc.conf` or `/etc/rc.conf.local`. Then you can run `service teamspeak start` to start it by hand, and it will be automatically restarted after a reboot.